# In-App purchase Issue : Purchase not persist

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am trying to enable a In built function through a non consumable purchase. I could retrieve my product and make a purchase but I got a issue in persisting the purchase. When I purchase the product,my button (disabled initially) in view controller has to be enabled and also I kept a label changing its name "purchased".After purchase my label text changes and button enabled, but when I stop and run back Xcode the label state only persists not my button it goes back to disabled state.

** view controller **

```
-(void)Purchased {
    Label.text = @"item has been purchased";
  _newview.enabled=YES;
   NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [saveapp setBool:TRUE forKey:k_Save];
    [saveapp synchronize];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *saveapp = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
    if (!saved) {
        /// not save code here

    NSLog(@"wooo");
    } else {
        ///saved code here
        Label.text = @"item has been purchased";
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

** purchased view controller **

```
-(void)UnlockPurchase {

    _buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [_homeViewController Purchased];
}
```

I called this "UnlockPurchase" in updated transactions delegate function. Now the worst case here is after purchase this "_buyButton" state gets back soon to enabled.

Is this steps correct or wrong ? How to make the purchase to persist ? Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the same code (to enable the button) in your viewDidLoad method, too…

```
…

bool saved = [saveapp boolForKey:k_Save];
….
} else {
        ///saved code here
        Label.text = @"item has been purchased”;

       //Disable BuyButton
       //Enable your DesiredButton

    }
```

**UPD**

add `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` to your method:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

...  
case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:[self UnlockPurchase];                
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
....
```

Comment: my "_buyButton" gets back still gets back to original position enabled once again ! help .coz every time when I tap a buy button (in VC) it shows purchase view controller were this "_buyButton" gets back to enabled when I stop and run from Xcode. rather "_buyButton" stays disabled until I stop and run back Xcode.

Comment: Show me how you did it to check and disable the buyButton. How many buyButton do you have?!

Comment: If you have 2 viewcontrollers with "buyButton" put the same method to check NSUserDefault in viewDidload

Comment: I have a two buttons in VC 1)PurchaseItem(action) which calls purchaseview ctrlr 2)view2(IBoutlet)disabled initially, after purchase its has enable.In purchaseview ctrlr two buttons 1)buyProduct(action)and(IBoutlet)buyButton 2)Restore(action).

Comment: Real problem is "buyButton", I've declared it globally and I've placed this ** _buyButton.enabled = NO;
    [_buyButton setTitle:@"Purchased" forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; ** in that else part (your answer).Exactly what happens is When I delete the app and Run back from Xcode then by restoring the purchase,"view2"button stays forever(no matter again if i stop and run Xcode) were "_buyButton" turns disabled at that time no matter even by switching views it stays same.The moment I stop and run back Xcode "_buyButton" gets to Enabled.

Comment: You are saving to NSUserDefault when "Restore IAP", too?

Comment: If you want ... you can send me (email) the 2 implementation file (you can keep only the buy/payment/restore action/method where you are disabling/enabling the all buttons and the viewDidLoad method)